# Is there a way to set a fixed Local Peer ID in a Substrate blockchain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, blockchain

I am currently working with a Substrate blockchain and I was wondering if there is a way to set a fixed Local Peer ID, instead of it being generated dynamically every time the node starts up. I have been unable to find any information on this in the documentation and would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Subkey](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/) to generate a node key, that you can then supply to the node using the `--node-key` option.